# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts.. why do i get this error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have this code:

```
Entry *entry = [Entry create];

NSOrderedSet *media = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] init];
entry.media = media;

EntryTableInfo *entryTableInfo = [[EntryTableInfo alloc] init];
entry.entryTableInfo = entryTableInfo;

[[CoreDataStore mainStore] save];
```

And when it saves, it's giving me the error `Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts`.

The `NSOrderedSet` code was already there, and was working fine. The `EntryTableInfo` code wasn't, that's new, and that's the cause of the crash, but I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `Entry` and `EntryTableInfo` classes are managed objects (subclasses of `NSManagedObject`).

Managed objects should 'live' only inside of a managed object context (`NSManagedObjectContext` object). Particularly they should be created only by and within such context.

Your `[Entry create]` method probably does so, but `[[EntryTableInfo alloc] init]` creates a managed object with no context, which is wrong.

Try looking at `[Entry create]` method implementation code and creating a `EntryTableInfo` instance in a similar way.